# Setting an environment variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using xp. I am facing problem in using Variables.

I am using following  code

@echo off
set var = "srting"

When i check the value of var using %

set %var%

Environment variable %var% not defined

Anyone help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute different code path based on file content, this should work for you:

```
@echo off
set FILE_CONTENT=string

for /f %%a in (file.txt) do set var=%%a

if %var%==%FILE_CONTENT% (
 goto MATCHED
 ) else (
     goto NOT_MATCHED
     )

 :MATCHED
 echo "matched"
 goto:EOF

 :NOT_MATCHED
 echo "Not matched"
 goto:EOF
```

However, if the file name contains '`spaces`' or '`(`' like in '`c:\program files(x86)`', the above code will not work. The workaround is to get the short name (probably using: ~dpsx) of the file and then use it.

Comment: Are you using a .bat file with the above code or are you issuing these commands from a cmd shell? If you are using cmd shell, replace '%%' with '%'. Also, do you have any special character in your file name?

Comment: No any special character in file name. But file text contain string, then : (colon symbol )then space and then some string.  script is reading upto : from file.

Comment: Okay, so you will have to modify the for loop to read space separated values. Use some "delims" tag with for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the space before and after the equals sign; IIRC, I think that can cause problems.

Also, you can't put more than one command on a line like that, you have to separate it with ampersands, or instead, change it to this:

```
@echo off
set var="srting"
```

---

Edit:

You said you try:

```
Set %var%
```

but %var% is a value, not a variable name. Is that really what you intended?

Comment: See my edit: was that a typo, or did you really mean to use `Set`?

Comment: thanks i was using space before and after the equals sign. now its working

Answer (score 1):

set %var% Environment variable %var% not defined

> White spaces are not allowed in setting variables in DOS batch file.
>
> Try this :
>
> > @echo off
> >
> > set var="srting"
> >
> > echo %var%

.... that should give you an output **"srting"** on next line.

> > If you try now - your own command : set %var%
> >
> > output should be : *"Environment variable srting not defined"*
> >
> > which in my view is correct. Hope that makes sense for you.