# Reading the content of a text file into an environment variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Actually I want to pas the content of txt file to if condition

I am trying the following

```
set /p var = < file name 
if not %var% == “string” goto x else goto y
```

But it's not working .

When I check value of var it shows variable not defied

```
Set %var%
```

> Environment variable %var% not defined

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568737/problem-in-setting-variables/

Answer (score 7):

```
echo sometext > testfile.txt
set /P someVar=<testfile.txt
if %someVar%==sometext (echo true) else (echo false)
```

From what I understood, this is the example to be based on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
echo %var%
```

to show the current contents of the variable `var`.

Answer (score 0):

now it's working. I was using space in set variable cmd.

set /P someVar=< file.txt

if "%someVar%"=="some text" (echo true) else (echo false)

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth noting that `"%var%"` has to be in quotes.  If you leave `%var%` without quotes and `%var%` contains `string` your statement becomes:

`if not string == "string" goto x else goto y`